# what layout components were used for Pocket Weather AU?

Tags: iphone, layout, uinavigationcontroller

Could anyone comment on what IOS components for navigation/layout etc were used for the iPhone application "Pocket Weather AU"?   It looks quite good the way it's set out.    I'm guessing:

Navigation Controller

- 1st Level - Contains a table view, with a tool bar at bottom
- 2nd Level - Detailed view - probably a custom page totally
- Then regarding the  "+" and "grid" button at top in main page - hopefully these are just buttons one can put into the standard Navigation Controller that can then trigger a separate view

**Main Screen**

[image]

**Details Screen**

[image]

PS. Also when the "+" symbol is pressed it goes to:

[image]

Comment: post screens. people wont download an app just for this comment

Comment: ok - just have done this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looks like a highly customized Plain Style UITableView in a UINavigationController on the first screen. Each cell has a transparent background image and the entire table view has a background image. It looks like Subtitle style cells. The weather thumbnail (sun, cloud, etc) is a UIImageVIew added as a subview to the cell or possibly the cell accessory. The high/low temperatures are just UILabels added as subviews to the cell.

The buttons on top are just UIBarButtonItems (Add and the Grid). They can be added in viewDidLoad, like so:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addAction:)] autorelease];
```

A UIToolBar is added as a subview containing two UIBarButtonItems (Edit and Refresh). There is also a UILabel subview in the UIToolBar and probably some Flexible Space for layout.

The second screen is a custom view controller. I would lay something like that in a .xib.

addAction would look something like this:

```
    FindLocationController *findLocationController = [[FindLocationController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
findLocationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
findLocationController.title = @"Find Location";

UINavigationController *findLocationNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:findLocationController];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:findLocationController animated:YES];

[findLocationController release];
[findLocationNavController release];
```

Comment: thanks - Oh, and in terms of how the "+" button on the main screen opens up the modal "Find Location" view?  How would you do this in iPhone, like would this be a manually throwing up a view, or would this be just another controller/view you could push onto the NavigationController?  thanks

Comment: Yes, I would presentModalViewController another UINavigationController with a UITableViewController as its rootViewController. See my edit.

Comment: thanks Keller - to understand things can I ask (a) why do you create a new UINavigationController, as opposed to using the main Nav controller from the main screen?, and (b) given we do have the custom FindLocationController then why do you need a UINavigationController in the mix?  i.e. why couldn't one just present the FindLocationController itself?

Comment: If you were to simply present the TableViewController without adding it as the root view of a new UINavigationController, you wouldn't have a Navigation Bar. If you alternately push the FindLocation view controller onto the existing UINavigationController, you wouldn't be able to use the "cover vertical" modal animation.